# sane does not recognize my scanner FB636U also MG3630 made by Canon

Tags: canon, sane

i tried  $scanimage -L

but not recogniged

my OS is Ubuntu Sutudio 18.04.2 which updated from 16.04.5

please  help me

i am Japanese and

i do not know how to install driver from makers deb file
so plz show me most easy way

Comment: Double clicking any Deb file should open the software installer.

Comment: yes i know sir,  but i do not know where i can download sane drivers

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation ... from "software", I deleted SANE once and reinstalled it, but when it was 16, 04-6, FB630U was able to call normally from GIMP and scan. However, upgrading to 18, 04-1 did not seem to recognize the scanner.